# Make URL point to .py file in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

I'm just now digging into GAE and I see two ways to make a particular URL pull up the right page.

The first way is using handlers:

```
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: helloworld.py
```

The other way is using the following:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', MainPage),
                                  ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                                 debug=True)
```

Which is better or which is right?  I don't fully understand what the second example is doing exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use both.  The section in [app.yaml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html) tells App Engine where to look for your WSGI application.  `application = webapp.WSGIApplication(...)` sets up your WSGI application using the [webapp](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html) framework.

**update:**

app.yaml:

```
handlers:
  - url: /city.*
    script: cityhandler.py
```

cityhandler.py

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/city', ShowCityPage)],
                                     debug=True)
```

Comment: Let's say I want domain.com/city to point to particular .py file. I'd have to setup the regex in app.yaml and then setup '/city', City in the WSGI application.  Is that correct?

Comment: Awesome, and perfect!  Oh, and thank you too!  That all makes sense.